# What happened in scheme when defining a symbol to be something else?

Tags: scheme, quote

I'm a beginner of the Scheme language.

Recently I found that the data type **symbol** can be displayed using quote, like this:

```
> 'E
E
> (quote E)
E
```

However, if the code below executed, every kind of quote may fail:

```
> (define 'E 123)
> 'E
E: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> 'abc
abc: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

[image]
So what happend when code `(define 'E 123)` being executed?

Comment: try `'1`, it's even funnier. it returns `123`!

Comment: Now I realized that the name `quote` has been redefined, to be a function of one parameter which always returns 123. Since the number 1 is a legal parameter, it will always return `123`.

Comment: right. :) one minor correction, 1 is not a parameter, it is an argument in the function call `(quote 1)`. `E` is a parameter in the new function definition of `quote`, `(lambda (E) 123)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you asked Scheme to evaluate `(define 'E 123)`. Let's put a quote in front of that, to see what it looks like without the `'` shorthand. You can always do this: quote any expression to ask Scheme, "What do you think this value is?"

```
 > '(define 'E 123)
=> (define (quote E) 123)
```

Well, in Scheme, `(define (x ...) ...)` is a shorthand for `(define x (lambda (...) ...))`: it's just a convenient shorthand for defining a function.  So in this case `(define (quote E) 123)` is the same as `(define quote (lambda (E) 123))`.  Thus, the symbol you are redefining is `quote`, and you define it to be a function of one parameter which always returns 123.

Next you asked to evaluate `'E`. Again let's expand that to look through the shorthand:

```
 > ''E
=> (quote E)
```

You now call the `quote` function you defined, and pass it the variable `E` as an argument. But `E` has not previously been defined, so this fails. If you wanted to, you could first define `E` to have any value, and then perhaps `'E` would return 123. It rather depends on what Scheme evaluator you are using: the one I found does not much appreciate it when you try to redefine `quote`, but apparently yours does not mind, so I suspect you would get 123, and that you would get the same result if you defined `abc` and then evaluated `'abc`.

Answer (score 0):

in general `(define name ...)` is converted in `(bind name)` at the beginning of the scope and in the place where `define` appears, it is executed `(set! name ...)`.  You need to define a symbol, not a `(quote name)`.  Because `define` is a special form, the rules of evaluation are particular, not general application -- `define` is not a function call.